# Is the formation of nitrogen dioxide spontaneous?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

I was studying Thermodynamics from [my Chemistry textbook](http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/kech106.pdf) (page 181-182, section 6.6 (a)).

I have a question regarding the following text from my book.

> Now let us examine the following reactions:
> $$\begin{align}
> \ce{1/2 N2(g) + O2(g) &-> NO2(g)} & \Delta_\mathrm{r}H^⦵ &= \pu{+33.2 kJ mol-1} \\
> \ce{C (graphite, s) + 2 S(l) &-> CS2(l)} & \Delta_\mathrm{r}H^⦵ &= \pu{+128.5 kJ mol-1}
> \end{align}$$**These reactions though endothermic, are
> spontaneous.**

I vistied the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Gibbs_free_energy_of_formation) on *Standard Gibbs free energy of formation* to check the values of $\Delta_\mathrm{f} G^⦵$ for $\ce{NO2}$ and $\ce{CS2}$ and verify if the above stated reactions were truly spontaneous. It turns out that $\Delta_\mathrm{f} G^⦵$ for $\ce{NO2}$ is $\pu{51.3 kJ mol-1}$; and $\Delta_\mathrm{f} G^⦵$ for $\ce{CS2}$ is $\pu{67.1 kJ mol-1}$.

I understand that as the change in entropy involved in the formation of $\ce{CS2}$ is positive, this reaction can be spontaneous at high temperatures even though it is not at $298 \pu K$.

This is not the case with the formation of $\ce{NO2}$ though. The change in entropy associated with its formation is negative and so $\Delta_\mathrm{f} G^⦵$ will always be positive. This means that this reaction will never be spontaneous.

Then why does my textbook state so?
Is that statement (bold text) wrongly stated or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: If $\Delta G°$ is positive, the reaction is not spontaneous. If $\Delta G°$ is negative, the reaction is spontaneous, but it can be rather slow, so slow that it does not appear to happen even for years. Your inverse reactions, namely the decompositions of $\ce{NO2}$ or of $\ce{CS2}$ are good examples of this extremely slow behavior.

Comment: Hi, please note my edits, particularly the MathJax usage. `\ce{...}` is supposed to be used only for chemical formulae and equations. $\Delta G$ isn't a chemical formula or equation, you shouldn't use it there, as it leads to the $G$ being incorrectly written upright. Then, your physical quantities with units (like x kJ/mol) are much better typeset using `$\pu{x kJ mol-1}$` rather than a mixture of `\text` and `\ce`. You may find https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/16683 useful as a guide.

Comment: Note that $\Delta G_\mathrm{f}(T)=\Delta H_\mathrm{f}(T)-T\Delta S_\mathrm{f}(T)$ and that for  $\Delta  S_\mathrm{f}(T) \gt 0$ and high enough T, those reactions may become spontaneous in spite of being endothermic.

Comment: @Silica19 Compare the respective $\Delta G_\mathrm{f}^°$ and $\Delta H_\mathrm{f}^°$ values to get the sign of $\Delta S_\mathrm{f}^°$. Additionally, for high temperatures, the standard values are not that important, but  $\Delta H_\mathrm{f}(T)$ and $\Delta S_\mathrm{f}(T)$, using integration of $\int{\Delta C \mathrm{d}T}$ resp. $\int{\frac{\Delta C}{T} \mathrm{d}T}$

Comment: @Poutnik I've added details about sign of entropy in my question accordingly.

Comment: Note that the thermodynamic spontaneity of compound formation is based on the $\Delta G_\mathrm{f} = \Delta G_\mathrm{f}^° + RT \ln{Q}=RT \ln{(Q/K)}$, where Q is the [reaction quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_quotient) and K is the equilibrium constant of the formation.